# Capture network traffic - protractor

Tags: protractor, browsermob-proxy

I have used Browermobpoxy with Selenium(Java) to capture the network traffic from client (Browser), it worked so good.

We recently inclined towards Protractor, 
My Question is
1) Is there a good NodeJS library available?
2) Is it possible to use the BrowerMobProxy.jar file inside protractor and (anyway) instantiate the browsermobpoxy object?

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but perhaps the npm browsermob-proxy package offers what you need.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/browsermob-proxy